# Is this planet's climate map realistic?

Tags: climate, geography, temperature

Here are three different maps of the planet that's going to be the main setting of a comic book I'm working on, each one showing something different:

[image: A map of a fictional planet, with latitude and longitude]

As you can see in the first image, I mapped out the wind currents (purple) and the ocean currents (dark blue). My cousin mapped out the different biomes of the planet. I also added the equator and prime meridian (red), as well as other significant points of the planet's latitude and longitude (yellow, green, blue).

[image: A map of different temperature ranges found across Odroia]

With the second image, I map out average temperatures, with red being the hottest regions and lavender being the coldest regions.

[image: A map of different yearly precipitation ranges found across Odroia]

The third image shows the yearly precipitation ranges, with a more saturated blue denoting more precipitation.

I do have some knowledge of climatology, and so does she, but I am asking an expert here: Are the biome placements, ocean currents, and average temperatures/yearly precipitations realistic? If not, what would be?

Comment: We've had various versions of this question since I've been a member, +1 for offering the most detailed and best pictures.

Comment: I love these maps and think you should run with them. You've done a great job! But how "realistic" do you need them to be? You're missing cell wind currents, but is that level of detail really necessary? After all, who's an expert concerning the wind currents of a fictional world? Keep in mind that "reality" (which isn't really what we do here) would require knowing the altitudes of mountains and deserts, the albedo of the deserts, the composition of the atmosphere.... So, when you say "realistic," what do you really mean?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks. I want to make sure that the information I send is easy to understand.

Comment: @JBH While the story was originally made by my cousin, I'm doing work on it because she's busy. I want it to be passable, while not going into too much detail. I went with the hottest regions being inland equatorial regions, and the dampest regions being on the side of mountains that ocean winds blow onto, etc.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong. I think the map is well beyond suspension-of-disbelief. I'm just pointing out that "realistic" is a big word on this site that applies less than 10% of the time because your audience is nowhere near educated enough in the art to know if you're right or wrong. Two thumbs up! Now get back to work... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map is quite realistic! I'll try my best to provide small improvements, as :

- Your large piece of land on the top right actually experiences quite a lot of rain, you might wanna make the preiciptation a bit darker there.
- I would suggest the circular ocean current in the very far bottom right to actually go outwards into main ocean *and* recircle back into the bay